# How to skip some conditions when using multiple where in linq

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause

I'm using multiple where filter items in my list. How to properly skip some where blocks, if some filter fields are empty?

```
IEnumerable<MyNewClass> filterResult = itemList.Where(s => s.name == nameFilterTextBox.Text)
                                                       .Where(s => s.description == descriptionFilterTextBox.Text)
                                                       .Where(s => s.color == (MyNewClass.Colors)comboBox1.SelectedIndex).ToList();
```

Comment: you can use specification pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some options here:

- you can use an `if` and only conditionally add a `Where` clause; or
- you can use logic such that the filter is `true` if the filter field is empty.

The first one can be resolved like:

`IEnumerable<MyNewClass> filterResult = itemList;
if(nameFilterTextBox.Text != "") {
    filterResult = filterResult.Where(s => s.name == nameFilterTextBox.Text);
} if(descriptionFilterTextBox.Text != "") {
    filterResult = filterResult.Where(s => s.description == descriptionFilterTextBox.Text)
} if(comboBox1.SelectedIndex != -1) {
    MyNewClass.Colors col = (MyNewClass.Colors)comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
    filterResult = filterResult.Where(s => s.color == col);
}
// do something with filterResult.ToList()`

The latter can be solved as follows: you change the filter:

```
s => some_condition
```

to:

```
s => filter_field_is_empty || some_condition
```

Such that if the `filter_field_is_empty` condition is `true`, it will thus let the element pass in the filter. Note that this will usually be **less efficient** because the test is done **for every element**:

```
IEnumerable<MyNewClass> filterResult = itemList
    .Where(s => nameFilterTextBox.Text == "" || s.name == nameFilterTextBox.Text)
    .Where(s => descriptionFilterTextBox.Text == "" || s.description == descriptionFilterTextBox.Text)
    .Where(s => comboBox1.SelectedIndex == -1 || s.color == (MyNewClass.Colors)comboBox1.SelectedIndex).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you. Only one remark: ComboBox.SelectedIndex returns -1 if no value selected, not null.

Comment: @Wuzaza: thanks. Modified. Somehow I forgot that (that's probably an effect of using all kinds of languages concurrently :S)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` in the `Where` clause. Here is the code:

```
IEnumerable<MyNewClass> filterResult = 
    itemList.Where(s =>
      (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nameFilterTextBox.Text) || s.name == nameFilterTextBox.Text) &&
      (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(descriptionFilterTextBox.Text) || s.description == descriptionFilterTextBox.Text) &&
      s.color == (MyNewClass.Colors)comboBox1.SelectedIndex).ToList();
```